# Aws ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Body, value:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda

I am writing the code in AWS lambda and I cannot pass data
like
[0,1,0,0,0,1.....]
it says parameter validation error any solutions as to how to pass the data?

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
import os
import io
import boto3
import csv
import numpy as np
from preprocessing import preproprocess
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['data']
    print(payload)
    # any_text= 'Hi sarah wondering what is the status of my order thanks soham'
    # order_status='Awaiting shipment'
    # eg= preproprocess(any_text,order_status)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                      ContentType='text/csv',
                                      Body=payload)
```

Here is the code to my model

```
%%writefile train.py
import pip
from pip._internal import main
def install(package):
    """install packages"""
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        main(['install', package])
install('s3fs')
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import s3fs

bucket_name  = 'testsvc'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    training_data_directory_path = "s3://testsvc/xgboost-as-a-built-in-algo/train/train.csv"
    train_data=pd.read_csv(training_data_directory_path)
    X_train=train_data.drop(columns=['tags'])
    y_train=train_data['tags']
    svc = SVC(kernel = 'rbf',C=10,gamma = 0.1)
    svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
    model_output_directory = os.path.join("/opt/ml/model", "model.joblib")
#     boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).Object(model_output_directory).upload_file('')
    print("Saving model to {}".format(model_output_directory))
    joblib.dump(svc, model_output_directory)
def model_fn(model_dir):
    """Deserialized and return fitted model

    Note that this should have the same name as the serialized model in the main method
    """
    clf = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return clf
```

When I am passing JSON data in test "0,1,0,0,...." I am getting an error that my data is not getting a 2d array it's a 1-d array please try to reshape it. when I am trying to change the formatting of test data there is a parameter validation error. Please help me some way around this thing.